# Issue generating a PHP variable as a custom QR Code

Tags: php, laravel, qr-code, laravel-blade

Am working on an application whereby am generating some QR code on Laravel blade file. I have some PHP variable containing some data and am embedding it into the src tag of an image as a QR code.

It works fine but the problem is when I generate the QR code and test with a QR scanner I get the actual PHP code instead of the value in the variable. For instance am getting this output on a QR scanner on my phone:     **echo $policy**

**Code on my template**

```
<div class="row">
     <img class="QR" src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->backgroundColor(255, 255, 255)->margin(0)->color(0, 0, 0)->size(52)->generate( '{{ $policy }}'))!!}" height="43" width="43">      
 </div>
```

Comment: Why `->generate( '{{ $policy }}'))`? You cant inject like that. `generate()` argument will be `"{{ $policy }}"`, not a `$policy` value

Comment: @Tarasovych   Do I add it inside generate method like geneerate({{ $policy }} )

Comment: @Tarasovych  Kindly explain with the whole code ...

Comment: Change `generate('{{ $policy }}')` to `generate($policy)`,

Comment: I have used this code `<img class="QR6" src="data:image/png;base64, {!! base64_encode(QrCode::format('png')->backgroundColor(255, 255, 255)->margin(0)->color(0, 0, 0)->size(52)->generate($policy) !!}" height="43" width="43"> `       and I get this error ` Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ',' or ')'
`

Comment: `generate($policy);`

Comment: you are missing a closing parenthesis for the `base64_encode` function, change `generate($policy)` to `generate($policy))`